# Find entities whose array attribute contains a string

Tags: flask, google-cloud-datastore

I am using Google Cloud Datastore and I have the following entity:

```
Question
{
  "title": "Who is it?",
  "categories": [
    {
      "catName": "Computer Science"
    },
    {
      "catName": "Biology"
    }
  ]
}
```

In Flask, how can I perform a query which finds all questions that have "Biology" in their category array?
Is it even possible to create such a filter?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

> ```
> query = client.query(kind='Question')
> query.add_filter('categories.catName', '=', 'Biology')
> result = list(query.fetch())
> ```